# How can I add authors to my blog pages?

Tags: functions

I use Wordpress as a school paper blog and I would like to have different authors for articles. How can I add some new authors other than my blog title?

Comment: What do you mean 'other than my blog title' ?

Comment: Why not add users with the ["Author" Role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Author)?

Answer (score 1):

Add some more authors in wp-admin, and if You would like to show author under a post, place:

```
<?php the_author(); ?>
```

in index.php, single.php or any other template file, that Your theme is using to show blog posts, single post, archive etc.